# Simple php : Adding how many users registered

Tags: php, authentication

Right, so I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS and I'm starting to try a bit of php. I'm coding a simple website and I'm adding a register and login system. I want on the header of my site for it to say how many users are registered. I have a 'users' table which is where usernames, emails etc are stored. But I'd like to know how to make the index site say how many users are reigstered. I can imagine this is very simple but I don't know much about php. So if you could help it would be great :)

Comment: If you store them in MySQL, you can do a simple `select` for it, ie `SELECT count(*) from usrTable`

Comment: What makes me sad is the thing you didn't put much effort into researching this matter, you just asked question....

Comment: Are you sending them a confirmation email? If not, then Jon's answer is correct. Else, you will have to do the SELECT with a WHERE clause selecting the flag for "Confirmed". I also agree with skywalker, you aren't being very clear here.